# changing vector values within in a different function from where it was allocated c++

Tags: c++, function, vector

This might be obvious but Im new to using vectors and could use some help. I have a vector i have defined in my main function and I want to change its values in a function call through referencing it like you would with an array.

```
int foo(vector<float> &lines){
    lines[1] = 2.5;
    lines[2] = 1.2;
    //etc
}

int main(){
    vector<float> lines(3);
    lines[0] = 5.4;
    foo(lines);
}
```

if I print off the vector values I get {5.4, 0, 0} what am I doing wrong?

edit:
Thanks for the help, Ive got it working now but to be honest Im not sure exactly what the problem was. Originally I was attempting to assign to the vector with this:

```
lines[lineCtr*2] = (float)rho;
lines[(lineCtr*2)+1] = theta;
```

This worked when lines was an array but not as a vector. When I changed the assignment in the foo function to this:

```
int pos0 = lineCtr * 2;
int pos1 = (lineCtr * 2) + 1;

lines[pos0] = (float)rho;
lines[pos1] = theta;
```

It works perfectly. Could anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: I expect you are not passing the vector by reference or the  function you expect to be called is not executing for some reason (inside an if that never is true?) since this should work. Time to use your debugger.

Comment: [Seems to work OK](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a1c73650b660239) - did you post the actual code ?

Comment: is `lineCtr` an int or a float/double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as written should work and do what you expect. Either you have a bug in your printing code, or this isn't the code you actually have in your own program.